# Orbeon: form builder in liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, orbeon

I'm new to orbeon and the form builder is really cool. But it can't be used when deployed into liferay.
I tried deploy orbeon into a tomcat server and built a form with the form builder, but i don't know how to export the form so i can deploy it into the orbeon instance in liferay.
Or do I have to create the form by xform and xhtml? Are all the type controls, selection controls and validation available in xform and xhtml?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the Form [Runner proxy portlet](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/form-runner-proxy-portlet-guide).

- deploy Orbeon Forms as servlet in Liferay/Tomcat or on a remote Tomcat
- deploy the Form Runner proxy portlet in Liferay
- create your form with Form Builder from the Liferay/Tomcat or remote Tomcat install
- publish the form
- configure the portlet to connect to the Form Runner server and load the form